# How to update React state inside Relay QueryRenderer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay

I have a problem with a small **React Relay** based project. The component is a form with input fields, which receives data from the server using **QueryRenderer**, and can send modified data via mutation.
The problem is that if you update the state inside **QueryRenderer**, then the component is rendered again, which will cause an infinite loop.
But the data received from the server must be brought into a state so that it can be updated and sent back to the server. How to do this in **Relay** applications? I would be grateful for any help. Below is a simplified code of my project.
P.S. Some tags taken from ant design.

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={environment}
  query={HeroAllPostQuery}
  render={({ error, props }) => {
    if (error) {
      return <div>{error.message}</div>;
    } else if (props) {
      let hero = props.viewer.allPosts.edges[0].node;
      this.setState({ name: hero.name });
      return (
        <Form>
          <Form.Item label="Hero name"><Input name='name' defaultValue={hero.name} value={this.state.name} onChange={this._handleChange} /></Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={() => {
            this._handleUpdateHero(hero.id);
          }}>Save</Button>
        </Form>
      );
    }
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }}
/>
```

The rest of the application - form handlers, **graphql** query, etc. work correctly, so I did not give them here. The problem is where to get the data received from the server, to use it in the form inputs, and then send the modified data through the mutation.